# Difference between feral and domesticated honey?

Tags: zoology, entomology, food, carbohydrates, food-chemistry

Is there any significant differences in composition (and/or taste) between the honey of wild ("feral") honeybees versus that of domesticated ones used in beekeeping?

Comment: I think your question is on-topic but just for info [cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) might also have been a possible place where to ask this question.

Comment: Domesticated bees are often used to fertilize crops, so their honey consists mainly of nectar from a single type of flower: e.g. clover, orange, alfalfa, blackberry, and more.  Feral honey (or honey from garden hives) presumably comes from a mix of whatever flowers happen to be growing around the hive.

Comment: @Remi.b Not so sure, since when it comes to cooking, wild honey can be pretty hard to come by!!! :-D